# Can grails application have RestController and normal controller (for GSP) for same domain class

Tags: rest, grails

Recently I need to create REST API for existing grails application. 
I am thinking that is it really  possible to have both of the controllers (Normal and Restful) for same domain class in one single grails application?

Which controller will handle the request if make a HTTP GET request?

Please discuss your thoughts or if it is possible at all please guide me how.

Answer (score 1):

We can define a new Controller to handle to REST API calls. e.g. In my app I have User as Domain Class and have UserController which return the data to GSP pages. I wanted to add REST API support (unfortunately) in the same app and I don't wanted to deal with mess it is already there in UserController. So I added new Controller UserRestController which will specifically handle the REST API calls and following mapping in UrlMappings.groovy which now works fine. Thanks to @codehx for helping me on this.

```
"/api/users"(controller: "userRest", parseRequest: true) {
            action = [GET: "list", POST: "save" }

"/api/users/$id"(controller: "usersRest", parseRequest: true) {
        action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Which controller will handle the request if make a HTTP GET request?*

As far as it is not possible to have two controllers with same name in grails app this will not be confusing.

Just use two different names for Normal controller and for your RESTFUL controller, so obviously the URL for accessing the two urls will be different.

Comment: Lets say I have a domain User and have mapping defined in UrlMappings

Comment: Lets say I have Domain as User and associated Controller as UserController (This is normal controller for GSP) and now I create new Controller for REST say UserRestController. What will be the UrlMapping. Because as far as I know we specify the domain class name and grails finds the related controller using naming convention.

Comment: No, that convention applies only when you create the controller, once created you have the freedom to put what ever you want, and in fact you can call your UserController to be CarController if you want to.